# Python : Awkward index out of range

Tags: python, string, runtime-error

I'm having a really awkward Index out of range error in Python. Doesn't really make sense to me.
Here is my code :

```
def binarytotext(listing):
    size = len(listing)
    phrase = ""
    for arguments in range(size):
        temp = listing[arguments]
        sizebin = 7
        aski = 0
        for arguments2 in range(sizebin):
            if (arguments2 == 1):
                inter = int(temp[arguments2]) * 64
                aski = aski + inter
            elif (arguments2 == 2):
                inter = int(temp[arguments2]) * 32
                aski = aski + inter
            elif (arguments2 == 3):
                inter = int(temp[arguments2]) * 16
                aski = aski + inter
            elif (arguments2 == 4):
                inter = int(temp[arguments2]) * 8
                aski = aski + inter
            elif (arguments2 == 5):
                inter = int(temp[arguments2]) * 4
                aski = aski + inter
            elif (arguments2 == 6):
                inter = int(temp[arguments2]) * 2
                aski = aski + inter
            elif (arguments2 == 7):
                inter = int(temp[arguments2]) * 1
                aski = aski + inter
        letter = chr(aski)
        phrase = phrase + letter
    return phrase
```

The code is running fine, and it actually works, but it throws me this error when it's done executing :

```
inter = int(temp[arguments2]) * 64
IndexError: string index out of range
```

It doesn't make sense to me as my function works fine until the end. It's really awkward. I don't understand.

Comment: What is the input you are using causing the function to crash?

Comment: This will happen if your string (`temp`) is ever smaller than `7`...

Comment: Use your debugger and watch.

Comment: If i do print(len(temp)), it shows 7, so there's no problem here.

Comment: temp = listing[arguments] is equal to 1011000 (binary)

Comment: `range(7)` is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`; it looks like you *think* it is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. If `temp` contains 7 items, the last one is `temp[6]`, and `temp[7]` will throw an IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra empty string at the end of `listing`. Your error is being triggered by the very first index `temp[0]`.

Note that your code rather un-pythonic. It's much better to use the index and some math to compute the multiplier for each bit, rather than needing to write it out explicitly for each case. And rather than iterating on a range and indexing to get the value, iterate on the iterable directly (use `enumerate` if you need the indexes too):

```
for temp in listing:
    for index, value in enumerate(temp):
        inter = int(value) * 64 >> index
        aski += inter
```

You could also use `int(temp, 2)` to convert your binary string directly to an integer, rather than converting it yourself. `"".join(chr(int(binary_string, 2)) for binary_string in listing)` does your whole function in a one-liner!